# Help with a function that is going out of scope (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to call `CancelAsync`, although `webClient` is out of scope.

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
}


private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webClient.CancelAsync();
}
```

Could someone show me how `webClient.CancelAsync()` could be called from this event handler please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ....
{
    WebClient webClient;

    private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webClient = new WebClient();
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webClient.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Note that this breaks if the user clicks the DownloadButton twice without canceling.

Answer (score 6):

You need to store the `WebClient` in a field in your class.